# How wrong is the using of such code

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-2.0

I got a code for calling async blocks.

```
    private delegate void MyDelegate();
    void Async(MyDelegate t) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(t));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }
```

And then:

```
Async(delegate() {
    // code
});
```

I'm using it, but I'm sure that this is not the right way to do this. What are the problems with this method?

Comment: Assuming you just want to fire off a new thread that runs some delegate, this is a perfect solution. Why do you think this is wrong, and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's wrong, but It looks lame every time when I want something to not block my gui to run it like this. Especially if I call it many times a second.

Comment: @blez: If you're calling this many times a second, you should almost certainly be using the thread pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems no point in declaring your own delegate, for one thing. Why not just:

```
void Async(ThreadStart t) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(t);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}
```

? Personally I can't see myself wanting to do this often enough (and with *no* way of finding out how the task is progressing) to warrant a separate method. If you're using .NET 4 you should look into the Task Parallel Library, which still allows you to fire off asynchronous tasks - but in a rather more fully-featured way. (EDIT: Okay, so you can't use that from .NET 2 - it's worth bearing in mind for the future though.)

You might also want to consider using the `BeginInvoke` method on delegates, which allows you to start them on the thread pool easily anyway - *and* pass arguments:

```
Action<string, int> action = (name, age) => { ... };

IAsyncResult result = action.BeginInvoke("Jon", 35, null);
// Now you can use result if you want...
```

EDIT: You've now said you'll be doing this several times a second. Assuming this is a short-running task, you almost certainly *should* be using the thread-pool for this. As well as the example above, you can also use [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) to add a task to the thread pool. This will be more efficient (through thread reuse) than creating a new thread each time you have a task.

Comment: I use it for heavy tasks and for many small ones (like 100 calls/second). Is using the threadpool always the better option? I haven't used Action, is that a third way to call async code?

Comment: @blez: `Action<,>` is just a sample delegate type (actually from .NET 3.5, but it's only a delegate type - you can declare your own, obviously). *All* delegates have `BeginInvoke` methods. You should definitely use the thread pool for the short-running tasks. The longer-running ones could sensibly use separate threads.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a delegate

```
private delegate void MyDelegate();
```

you can do this

```
new MyDelegate(delegate
{
    // code
}).BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

It'd use thread pool threads so you don't wind up overwhelming the runtime with too many threads.